How can I split a database table into two?
I have a database table. There are quiz questions and 40 thousand records.
In the table; There are columns id, questionid, question, answer a, answer b, answer c, answer d and correct answer.
Now I want to do this: divide it into two tables: questions and answers.
Questions table; It must consist of id and question.
Answer table; It should be in the form of id, question ID, answer and correct answer. However, in the old record there are 4 lines for each question answer and it should be the same in this one too.
Example;
Questions table:
|id|question
answer table:
|id|1|a|0
|id|1|b|0
|id|1|c|1
|id|1|d|0

How can I achieve this in the easiest way for 40 thousand questions?
I created a json file, but I could not split the answers line by line.

Are you asking how to redesign the database? Or how to write a script to transform this data? Presumably the new tables should also be in your database? If so then it's hard to see where JSON fits in - shouldn't this be a sql question?

I'm asking how to split existing database files into two tables in the easiest way. @ADyson

The first thing to do is create the two tables ... have you done this yet? (I also see no need for json files, btw). I don't know about "easiest" ways but if you just write some insert sql it seems very "easy" - I'm not sure if you know how to create tables or not, or just don't know how to write sql queries for inserting data.

You can create the data for the answer table with a UNION query that selects each answer X column into its own row. E.g. SELECT id AS question_id, 'a' AS answer_name, answer_a AS answer, (answer = 'A') AS correct FROM questions_answers

@topsail Yes, the SQL side is difficult because I don't know SQL. That's why I'm looking for easy methods in different languages.

@Barmar Are we closing this as needing more focus?

To divide one big table to two tables, you can do following.
Supposing actual table :
quiz
-----------
id
question_id # What is the diff with id ?
question    # Question label
answer_a    # Answer A label
answer_b    # etc.
answer_c
answer_d
correct_answer  # Correct answer label (?)

And target tables :
question
-----------
id
question

answer
-----------
id
question_id
ordinal     # For consistant display order
answer
is_correct  # Could/should be question.correct_answer_id

Create question table :
create table question as
select all question_id as id, question
from quiz;

Create answer table :
create table answer as
select all question_id, 'A' as ordinal, answer_a as answer, (answer_a = correct_answer) as is_correct from quiz
union all
select all question_id, 'B' as ordinal, answer_b as answer, (answer_b = correct_answer) as is_correct from quiz
union all
select all question_id, 'C' as ordinal, answer_c as answer, (answer_c = correct_answer) as is_correct from quiz
union all
select all question_id, 'D' as ordinal, answer_d as answer, (answer_d = correct_answer) as is_correct from quiz;

alter table answer
add column id int unsigned auto_increment primary key first;

